# Generate Apriori frequent itemsets efficiently

Tags: python, apriori, market-basket-analysis

I'm trying to generate frequent itemsets efficiently using the Apriori principal. My current attempt is to use combinations from itertool but it generated an unnecessary number of itemsets. I need to follow Apriori principal while generating them i.e.

> If an itemset is infrequent, then all its supersets must also be infrequent.

My current attempt is very inefficient.

```
import itertools as it
def generateItemsets(Lk,k):

    comb = sum(Lk.keys(), tuple())
    Ck = set(it.combinations(comb, k))
    return Ck
```

Comment: I was thinking for a lot of time and made some code too. It appeared that your task is quite difficult to make efficient in pure Python or Numpy, it needs a lot of coding. If generic case needs to be solved, when we're given any input set of sets L. For the case if we need to just create all combinations it is solved very easily, and your code is doing this already quite efficiently, I would just suggest using `set(comb)` instead of `comb` because if `comb` has many duplicates then itertools will generate a lot of duplicate combinations, which is the main reason of inefficiency.

Answer (score 1):

you might consider FPgrowth / FPMax, user guide might be of help to you.
FYI: http://rasbt.github.io/mlxtend/user_guide/frequent_patterns/fpmax/

Also, there might be tons of one line items, eg: convenience stores you might just purchase a coke or a coffee. You might consider something like adding the row total and use row total > 1, this will screen out alot of insignificant data.